# Would atomic level welding actually work? For any solid materials?

Tags: technology, physics, materials, tools

In some fiction, there's a welding technique where say, 2 pieces of metal are cut in a way that creates a perfect edge/surface, absolutely flat down to the atomic level, with no impurities or distortions introduced. The pieces of metal, touched or pressed together, in effect form a monolithic piece of metal, welded at the atomic level, as their structures can join across enough of the common surface for that to happen.

(Note this isn't the same as friction based welding or other joins based on melting the metal at the joint. There's no actual movement involved and no emphasis on heating or melting of any kind.)

Handwaving aside the near-instantaneous surface degradation and/or surface pollution by whatever makes up the nearby environment, that would happen after such a cut, is this actually technically possible? For any solid materials at all? Or just some?

Comment: Could you give us some worldbuilding context for this?

Comment: real welding is atomic level, right now this question is too vague and context-less to answer.

Comment: VTO really suprised the q raised any difficulties, especially details and clarity, it is well written and adresses most of the problems of the situation and could not be more clear. It similar to coldwelding, which is a typucal problem in space applications as an example, and it more than a legit question of applicanility of that to other things including non metalls. Obiviously answer is yes and no, it just needs meat of words.

Comment: I would write meta on it, but  I can't post there as it crashes my browser when posting on mobile, but WB feels like WW specifically targeting technology questions, only fantasies are allowed, greaat what can I say. U do not know the topic, do not vote on it, there is skip button in revq specifically for the purpose.

Comment: @MolbOrg, nice from you to suppose that close votes are cast out of ignorance on the topic of the question. That's not the case. What lacks is any hint to details about the worldbuilding context where the answer has to be framed, else it is a perfectly sound technology question which doesn't belong here.

Comment: Important refeshment, of the motto of wb, another meta post worthy topic, but same problem. - "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for _writers, artists and others_ using _science_, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and _settings_." - it not only worlds, settings as well, so as elements of those. WB is the place to bundle diversity of topics for convinince of those who create. U too much focusing on W in WB, even if it is vague.   Should we stop be excited https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5208/20315 and move to scify then

Comment: I mean things progressed soo far, as to _demand_ story behing the question! And when story provided to use it as to say what a fluffy stuff, so if story is not up to someones liking, questions stops be considered at all. I'm just curious, do u see a problem here, u do not even need to make it available to public, just in good old way like last time.

Comment: I didn't think, if someone asks will lasers work against spaceships, could an earthlike planet exist the size of the sun", and other SciFi writing plausibility checks, that the OP needs to formally state "in my world" or "in my story", to avoid it being closed.  The bad faith here is saddening, this is asked here to check if its a valid technology or a fantasy one, to work as part of an end twist, with a short story that I'd like to ensure is scientifically plausible.  Do writers really have to spell that out, friends? Does it belong now? I'm left a bit disappointed in a minority of people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't fiction, the effect is known as [cold welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding).  From the link:

> Cold welding was first recognized as a general materials phenomenon in
> the 1940s. It was then discovered that two clean, flat surfaces of
> similar metal would strongly adhere if brought into contact while in a
> vacuum.

Comment: _"single-crystalline ultrathin gold nanowires can be cold-welded together within seconds by mechanical contact alone, and under remarkably low applied pressures. High-resolution transmission electron microscopy and in-situ measurements reveal that the welds are nearly perfect, with the same crystal orientation, strength and electrical conductivity as the rest of the nanowire."_ (Wikipedia link you gave) - this is perfect, exactly what I was trying to discover. A bit of handwaving on scale and we have my new world's most versatile workshop tool!

Comment: Grumpy, they closed the q, will u vote open as well? @Stilez I would not say that things will work that well for any substance, it quite easy to find demonstrations with gold wires, try to look on youtube, and in general the effect is real and useful. There is somwat similar, to friction welding, Explosion welding - I would say it is inbetween . Look at this video as well https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yjSf7Yh9UZc , that surface layer plays a role and properties of it, so it may not work, even in ideal conditions, with all materials,. WB feels broken, such an interesting q been closed.